# Online image hosting service with shared user interface and administration

Tags: images, uploader

I would like a web service to give some people the chance to upload files.

- They don't need an account, but password protection would be nice.
- The webfrontend should work pretty for mobile.
- The users will have to upload images, so it would be nice if images are shown as tumbnails after upload.
- It would also be nice, if users wold get a link after uploading, that they could use to delete the files themself

nice things are not necessary, first of all it should be simple nice looking "drop files" tool. I like share.riseup.net, but there you can only upload single files and the files are encrypted. I need to have the files unencrypted on my service.

Comment: Local or remote server?

Comment: remote server, but whats the difference?

Comment: You need a simple uploading service to let users to upload files ah, then you'll need to get a server, a domain and a php script. I don't remember if there was a image hosting website which you can manage user rights.